# LNK1104: cannot open file 'tomcryptd.lib' in QT creator

Tags: c++, qt

So, I'm trying to run this example program in qt using the tomcrypt library and when I tried to build the project the compiler threw this error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'tomcryptd.lib', I added the tomcrypt library using the "Add library" interface and these are the contents of the .pro file:

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++17 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

#You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
#In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

TRANSLATIONS += \
    ProjectM2_en_US.ts
CONFIG += lrelease
CONFIG += embed_translations

#Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../libraries/libtomcrypt/lib/ -ltomcrypt
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../libraries/libtomcrypt/lib/ -ltomcryptd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../libraries/libtomcrypt/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../libraries/libtomcrypt/include
```

I have tried searching for solutions but so far, I have not found one that worked for me. I'll be really thankful if anyone has a solution for my problem

Comment: So you are claiming that the file `tomcryptd.lib` is in the location `$PWD/../../libraries/libtomcrypt/lib/`. Where do you think that location is? Does that location contain the file `tomcryptd.lib`? It will help solve your problem if you can supply basic information like this. The most likely reason for your error is that the library is not in the place you are saying that it is, so that is the first possibility to examine.

Comment: Also saying what platform you are on would help as well. I'm assuming Windows but you haven't actually stated that.

Comment: $PWD/../../libraries/libtomcrypt/lib/ is in my project directory and yes, the location does not contain tomcryptd.lib but it does contain tomcrypt.lib. the platform that I am using is Windows

Comment: Well that is the reason for the error. It's worth trying a release build (if you have not already) just to check that tomcrypt.lib is OK. Then the next question to ask yourself is why the debug version of the library is missing and what you can do to fix that. Since I don;t know anything about this library I'm not sure I can help with that.

Comment: Seems this library is distributed as source only, so it's up to you to build the debug version of the library if that is what you want to use.